# Faster RCNN pretrain model training error

Tags: python, tensorflow, training-data, pre-trained-model, faster-rcnn

Tensorflow : 2.10.1
Python 3.10.0

Pretrained model:faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_640x640_coco17_tpu-8

When running the code

```
TRAINING_SCRIPT = os.path.join(paths['APIMODEL_PATH'], 'research', 'object_detection', 'model_main_tf2.py')

command = "python {} --model_dir={} --pipeline_config_path={} --num_train_steps=2000".format(TRAINING_SCRIPT, paths['CHECKPOINT_PATH'],files['PIPELINE_CONFIG'])
```

It shows output error as below

ValueError:  is not supported for tf version 2. See `model_builder.py` for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow.

How to solve this error.

Comment: Hi @Chengkaichew The error message you're encountering indicates that the specific feature extractor you're trying to use is not compatible with TensorFlow version 2. Given that you are using TensorFlow 2.10.1 and attempting to use the **faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_640x640_coco17_tpu-8 model**, you may need to update your TensorFlow Object Detection API or choose a compatible pre-trained model.